# Update TextView using Timer and ArrayList

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist, timer

I am writing a small program to update TextView in every 5 seconds. But I am unable to update my textview's text in every 5 seconds, especially when it comes to last arraylist item, like: C in below code

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34849284/update-textview-using-timer-and-arraylist) tutorial

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Timer timer;
 MyTimerTask myTimerTask;
 List<String> list;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  textCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter);

  timer = new Timer();
  myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

  timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 1000, 5000);

  ....  

  list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add("A");
  list.add("B");
  list.add("C");

 }

 class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

  @Override
  public void run() {

   runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
     for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        textCounter.setText(list.get(i).toString());
     }
     }});
   }}
```

Comment: Instead of iterating list, Why don't you set TextView with one Text at a time.

Comment: Do not use timer task it is not working properly , use handler for this.

Comment: where you call timer.start() method to start Timer.

Comment: I am using this tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html

Comment: is your TextView always display last item of list?

Comment: if you try to display for every 5 seconds,you have to find position of list what textview contains,get the index of  text list.indexOf(txt.getText().toString()); if result is 0 take first element otherwise add one to index value

Answer (score 2):

Don't iterate list every time run method called. Instead get one item from list and set it to TextView.

```
private int count =0;
private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                textCounter.setText(list.get(count%list.size).toString());
                count++;
            });
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sun I have just modified few line in your code. Did you understand above code?

Comment: @Sun You just need modify `MyTimerTask` class not all code.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `TimerTask` You should use `Handler` for Updating `TextView`.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     int count = 0;
     @Override
     public void run() {
         count++;
         textCounter.setText(list.get(count).toString());
         mHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000); // five second in ms
     }
};
mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Change your
    **MyTimerTask** class as given below.

```
private int position = 0;

class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (position >= list.size()) {
                    position = 0;
                }

                textCounter.setText(list.get(position).toString());
                position++;

            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you want to show list items again and again. I have edited my answer again now it will show each item just once and when last item shown to you timer will stop. @Sun

Comment: No I would like to show list items again and again, first show a-z then again a-z and so on... please update your code

Comment: @Sun My code is working exactly same as you want. I have tested this before posted and I have tested it now also. If problem comes again. Update your question with this MyTimerTask class.

Answer (score 1):

here I have Some Code Snippet which is just update Textview After every 5 Seconds.

**Step 1:**
First you are just making one saperate method where Textview is Update like following.

```
 private void updateTextView(){
    /**
     * Write Your Textview Update Code
     */

}
```

**Step 2**
Declare object of Runnable class which is Just Call updateTextview method after some specific time.

```
 Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        updateTextView();

    }
};
```

**Step 3**
you can Start this runnable using following code.

```
YOUR_TEXTVIEW.postDelayed(run,5000);
```

I hope you are clear with my Idea.

**Best of Luck**